# Execution time exceeded by slow query on MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have 20 tables and I want to fetch record by comparing the data.

These tables have more than 5000 records.

Now the problem is that the data fetching is very slow and one error is generated instead of showing the data

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

that is in PHP and the query is "$query1 = "SELECT  employees.*,upgradations.EmpID, upgradations.BPZ,picture.PicPath , designation.Designat 
    FROM 
                upgradations,employees,picture,designation
    WHERE 
                upgradations.Designationz=designation.Code
                AND upgradations.UPStatus=1
                AND picture.EmpID=employees.EmpID
                AND upgradations.EmpID=employees.EmpID
                AND employees.DEntry='$UCNIC'
                ORDER BY employees.ID ASC LIMIT $start, $limit ";"

Comment: Do you have indexes set up properly?

Comment: No one will be able to help without knowing the following information: A) What is the query; B) How are you using it? Are you using MySQLi, PDO or MySQL extension; C) (Optional) Version of php, mysql and your server.

Comment: i have edit my question as your requirement kindly check my question again. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to exceed the maximam exicutaion time in your php.ini file

```
 ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
```

Comment: $query1 = "SELECT  employees.*,upgradations.EmpID, upgradations.BPZ,picture.PicPath , designation.Designat 
 FROM 
    upgradations,employees,picture,designation 
 WHERE 
     upgradations.Designationz=designation.Code
    AND upgradations.UPStatus=1
     AND picture.EmpID=employees.EmpID
     AND upgradations.EmpID=employees.EmpID  
    AND employees.DEntry='$UCNIC'
    ORDER BY employees.ID ASC LIMIT $start, $limit ";

Answer (score 0):

in php.in file

search ini_set

change to  this one

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 1000); //1000 second
```